# figures and the captions do not get centered on an A3 page in A4 document and page numbering gets changed

Tags: typearea

I wrote the code below in which an A3 is inserted into an A4 document. once A3 is inserted all the formatting gets messed up. I tried several solutions and now many problems's been solved. but, still the page number on A3 page is in the middle where I want it to be on the right side bottom corner and the figures are not centered. Also, when I tried to comeback to A4 again everything get messed up. It would be a great help if you could give a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{capt-of,color}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\tikzstyle{rect} = [rectangle,rounded corners,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1.5cm,text centered,text width=3cm,draw=black,fill=blue!9]
\tikzstyle{circle1} = [circle, thick, draw=orange, minimum height=4mm]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage



\newpage
\subsection{Approved Cadre and Current Staff Members}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X  X }
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] 01.Project Director:
        \item[] 02.Dep. Project Director (Business Promotion)
        \item[] 03.Dep. Project Director (Infrastructure)
        \item[] 04.Senior Engineer (Electrical/ICT)
        \item[] 05.Senior Engineer (Civil)  
        \item[] 06.Engineer (Electrical/Electronics)    
        \item[] 07.Engineer (Civil)
        \item[] 08.Business Development Officer
        \item[] 09.Planning Coordinator
        \item[] 10.Town Planner 
        \item[] 11.Quantity Surveyor
        \item[] 12.Technical Officer 01
        \item[] 13.Land Officer 
        \item[] 14.Planning Officer 
        \item[] 15.Project Secretary
        \item[] 16.Admin. Officer
        \item[] 17.Management Assistant 01
        \item[] 18.Management Assistant 02
        \item[] 19.Management Assistant 03
        \item[] 20.Computer Operator 01
        \item[] 21.Computer Operator 02
        \item[] 22.Computer Operator 03
        \item[] 23.Office Employee Assistant 01 
        \item[] 24.Office Employee Assistant 02
    \end{itemize}

    &

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] \tikzmark{A}{Eng. Lal Premanath}
        \item[] \tikzmark{B}{Mr. Rahula Senanayake}
        \item[] \tikzmark{C}{\textbf{Vacant}}
        \item[] \tikzmark{D}{Mr. S.M.D.M. Ajith}
        \item[] \tikzmark{E}{Mrs. Chandanie Jayathilake}
        \item[] \tikzmark{F}{Ms. Devni Asheka}
        \item[] \tikzmark{G}{Ms. Shavini Avanthika}
        \item[] \tikzmark{H}{Mr. Thanuka Sasith}
        \item[] \tikzmark{I}{Ms Chathurangani Amarasekara}
        \item[] \tikzmark{J}{\textbf{Vacant}}
        \item[] \tikzmark{K}{\textbf{Vacant}}
        \item[] \tikzmark{L}{Ms. Chamli Shashiprabha}
        \item[] \tikzmark{M}{\textbf{Vacant}}
        \item[] \tikzmark{N}{Ms. Prabhashini Subasinghe}
        \item[] \tikzmark{O}{Ms. Kanthi Samarawickrama}
        \item[] \tikzmark{P}{\textbf{Vacant}}
        \item[] Ms. Shehani Kaushalya
        \item[] Ms. Sandali Lakchani
        \item[] Mr. Navin Ranasinghe 
        \item[] Mr. Sharaka Harsha
        \item[] Ms. Pawani Perera
        \item[] Ms. Nadeesha Mayadunna 
        \item[] Mr. Sasika Ekanayake
        \item[] Mr. Mangala Amith 

    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

    \coordinate (top A) at ($(A.north east)+(1cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (bottom A) at ($(A.south east)+(1cm,0)$);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (top A) -- node[right] {PS1} (top A |- bottom A);

    \coordinate (top B) at ($(B.north east)+(1cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (bottom C) at ($(C.south east)+(1cm,0)$);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (top B) -- node[right] {PS2} (top B |- bottom C);

    \coordinate (top D) at ($(D.north east)+(2cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (bottom E) at ($(E.south east)+(2cm,0)$);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (top D) -- node[right] {PS3} (top D |- bottom E);

    \coordinate (top F) at ($(F.north east)+(3cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (bottom J) at ($(J.south east)+(3cm,0)$);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (top F) -- node[right] {PS4} (top F |- bottom J);

    \coordinate (top K) at ($(K.north east)+(5cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (bottom K) at ($(K.south east)+(5cm,0)$);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (top K) -- node[right] {PS5} (top K |- bottom K);

    \coordinate (top L) at ($(L.north east)+(2.5cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (bottom P) at ($(P.south east)+(2.5cm,0)$);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (top L) -- node[right] {PS6} (top L |- bottom P);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\newpage
 %---------------------------------------------------------

{\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth

 \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]

    \node (ps1) [rect] {PD-Tech City};
    \node (ps21) [rect,below of=ps1] {DPD- Infrastructure}; 
    \node (ps22) [rect,below of=ps1,xshift=13.3cm] {DPD- Business Promotion}; 
    \node (ps31) [rect,below of=ps21,xshift=-6cm] {Senior Eng Roads, Sewer, Water, Drainage};
    \node (ps32) [rect,below of=ps21,xshift=7.5cm] {Senior Eng Electrical/ICT};
    \node (ps41) [rect,below of=ps31,xshift=-2.5cm] {Civil Eng};
    \node (ps42) [rect,below of=ps21,xshift=4cm,yshift=-2.5cm] {Town Planner};
    \node (ps43) [rect,below of=ps32] {Electrical Eng};
    \node (ps44) [rect,below of=ps22,yshift=-2.5cm] {Business Development Officer};
    \node (ps45) [rect,below of=ps1,xshift=-15cm,yshift=-5cm] {Planning Coordinator};
    \node (ps46) [rect,below of=ps31,xshift=2.5cm] {Architect};
    \node (ps51) [rect,below of=ps41,xshift=2.5cm] {QS};
    \node (ps52) [rect,below of=ps42] {GIS officer};
    \node (ps61) [rect,below of=ps46,xshift=0,yshift=-2.5cm] {Draughtsman};
    %\node (ps62) [rect,below of=ps43,xshift=2cm,yshift=-2.5cm] {Pr. Secretary};
    %\node (ps63) [rect,below of=ps42,yshift=-2.5cm] {Land Officer};
    \node (ps64) [rect,below of=ps52] {Planning Officer};
    %\node (ps65) [rect,below of=ps43,xshift=6cm,yshift=-2.5cm] {Admin. Officer};
    \node (ps66) [rect,below of=ps41,xshift=0,yshift=-2.5cm] {Technical officer};
    \node (MA4) [rect,below of=ps66] {MA-4};
    \node (CO2) [rect,below of=ps61] {CO-2};
    \node (Driver3) [rect,below of=MA4,xshift=2.5cm] {Driver-3};
    \node (CO4) [rect,below of=ps64] {CO-4};
    %\node (level1) [circle1,right of=ps1,xshift=-5cm] {PS1};
    %\node (level2) [circle1,right of=ps21,xshift=-5cm] {PS2};
    %\node (level3) [circle1,right of=ps31,xshift=-5cm] {PS3};
    %\node (level4) [circle1,right of=ps41,xshift=-5cm] {PS4};
    %\node (level5) [circle1,right of=ps51,xshift=-5cm] {PS5};
    %\node (level6) [circle1,right of=ps61,xshift=-5cm] {PS6};

    %\draw [arrow] (ps1)|-(ps21);

    \coordinate (below ps1) at ($(ps1.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$);
    \draw [arrow] (ps1.south)--(below ps1)--++(0,0)--(ps21.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps1.south)--(below ps1)--++(13.3cm,0)--(ps22.north);


    \coordinate (below ps21) at ($(ps21.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$);
    \draw [arrow] (ps21.south)--(below ps21)--++(7.5cm,0)--(ps32.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps21.south)--(below ps21)--++(-6cm,0)--(ps31.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps21.south)--(below ps21)--++(2cm,0)--++(0,-6.25cm)--(ps51.east);


    \draw [arrow] (ps21.south)--(below ps21)--++(4cm,0)--(ps42.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps32.south)--(ps43.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps22.south)--(ps44.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps42.south)--(ps52.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps52.south)--(ps64.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps64.south)--(CO4.north);

    \coordinate (below ps31) at ($(ps31.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$);
    \draw [arrow] (ps31.south)--(below ps31)--++(-2.5cm,0)--(ps41.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps31.south)--(below ps31)--++(2.5cm,0)--(ps46.north);



    \coordinate (above ps66) at ($(ps66.north)+(0,0.3cm)$);
    \draw [arrow] (ps31.west)--++(-3cm,0)--++(0,-6.43cm)--(above ps66)--(ps66.north);
    %\draw [arrow] (ps31.south)--(below ps31)--++(-2cm,0)--(ps41.north);

    \coordinate (above ps61) at ($(ps61.north)+(0,0.3cm)$);
    \draw [arrow] (ps31.west)--++(-3cm,0)--++(0,-6.43cm)--(above ps61)--(ps61.north);

    \coordinate (above CO2) at ($(CO2.north)+(0,0.3cm)$);
    \coordinate (above MA4) at ($(MA4.north)+(0,0.3cm)$);
    \coordinate (above Driver3) at ($(Driver3.north)+(0,2.8cm)$);
    \draw [arrow] (ps21.south)--(below ps21)--++(2cm,0)--++(0,-10.18cm)--(above CO2)--(CO2.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps21.south)--(below ps21)--++(2cm,0)--++(0,-10.18cm)--(above MA4)--(MA4.north);
    \draw [arrow] (ps21.south)--(below ps21)--++(2cm,0)--++(0,-10.18cm)--(above Driver3)--(Driver3.north);
    %       \draw [arrow] (ps32)--(ps43);
    %       \draw [arrow] (ps65)--(support);


    %       \coordinate (below ps22) at ($(ps22.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$);%
    %       \draw [arrow] (ps22.south)--(below ps22)--++(2cm,0)--(ps45.north);
    %       \draw [arrow] (ps22.south)--(below ps22)--++(-2cm,0)--(ps44.north);


    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Organization Chart of Tech City Development Project}
\end{center}    
\end{figure}    


\clearpage

 %}

 %--------------------------------------------------------------

 \newpage       

 \subsection{Progress in Road Affairs}

 \subsubsection{Outcomes of Progress Review Meeting}

  At the Progress Review Meeting held on 13th December 2017, the following 
  roles \& responsibilities were agreed upon. 


  \begin{longtable}{|l|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|}

  \caption{List of Roles \& Responsibilities agreed at Progress Review 
   Meeting }\\
  \hline
 Project&Responsible Agency& Role\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Access road from Kottawa to Mahenwatta}&UDA&Land acquisition 
 \\ \cline{2-3}  
 &RDA&Design\\ \cline{2-3}
 &PRDA&Contractor for Dampe - Pitipana section\\ \hline

 \multirow{4}{*}{Roads under PRDA jurisdiction}&RDA&Design (using the 
  provision from UDA's Sukithapurawara projects for 2018)\\ \cline{2-3}

  &TCDP& Procure and outsource the construction/ improvement works\\ 
  \cline{2-3}  
  &UDA&Land acquisition\\ \cline{2-3}  
  &PRDA&Supervise the construction/ improvement works \\ \hline  

  Construction of internal roads& &\\ \hline   

  \end{longtable}






  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of packages `typearea` and `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand*\normalpage{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=portrait}\recalctypearea
  \newgeometry{top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=0.5in}%
}
\newcommand*\largepage{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=a3,paper=landscape,usegeometry}\recalctypearea
  \newgeometry{top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=0.5in}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\normalpage}

\usepackage{tikz}% loads also graphicx, xcolor, ...

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}% <- recalculate \headwidth

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\largepage
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \tikz\node[fill=lightgray,minimum width=.8\textwidth,minimum height=.9\textheight]{};
  \caption{Organization Chart of Tech City Development Project}
\end{figure}
\normalpage
\subsection{Progress in Road Affairs}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot sir This'd be the best solution for ever